# Converting a comma separated list of json objects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a problem with a received javascript object.
I receive something like this:

```
{
 "name":"a",
 "surname":"b"
},
{
 "name":"c",
 "surname":"d"
},
{
 "name":"e",
 "surname":"f"
}
```

I store it in a variable and I would like to have an array of json objects, i.e. a JSON Array .

[{
 "name":"a",
 "surname":"b"
},
{
 "name":"c",
 "surname":"d"
},
{
 "name":"e",
 "surname":"f"
}]

I would need something as array.push() but I can't do it if I don't split the file before.

Comment: What is the desired output? I don't really understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: I would like to have an array like this:
array[0] = {"name":"a","surname":"b"};
array[1] = {"name":"c","surname":"d"};

Comment: I don't understand what is that hard to do...anyway, seems like Yeldar K. gave you the answer.

Comment: if you are receiving just objects as arguments just loop through and add it to your array. If that make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an invalid notation - either JavaScript object or JSON. If you can fix your input or can make someone fix it, then it is definitely better to make your data source be valid.

However, sometimes we have to work with wrong data (external providers etc.), then you can make it a valid JSON array by adding a couple brackets in the beginning and the end:

```js
var str = '{ "name":"a",  "surname":"b" }, {  "name":"c",  "surname":"d" }, {  "name":"e",  "surname":"f" }';
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + str + "]");
//console.log(arr);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  console.log("Name #" + (i + 1) + ": " + arr[i].name);
  console.log("Surname #" + (i + 1) + ": " + arr[i].surname);
}
```

It can look a little bit hacky, but it is the best thing you can do when you have to work with such input.
It looks much better than trying to split an object by commas manually, at least for me.

Comment: So as an alternative you suggest me to modify the input file before this arrives to me?

Comment: @VinsMat It always better to solve the origin of problem, so, if you can make your input come in a valid JSON format, then yes, **it is better to fix it there** :) But sometimes we **have to** work with invalid format (external providers etc.) - then my one-line hack will help you.

Comment: No, he's saying to modify the response after you get it, although I would ask myself why do I get that response in the first place and I would try to modify it there to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have one function to split your Array of Objects in many Arrays as you want, see the code :)

```
var BATCH_SIZE = 2;

var fullList = [{name:"a",surname:"e"},{name:"a",surname:"e"}
  , {name:"a",surname:"e"},{name:"a",surname:"e"}, {name:"a",surname:"e"}];

Batchify(fullList,BATCH_SIZE);

function Batchify(fullList,BATCH_SIZE){
    var batches = [];
    var currentIndex = 0;
    while (currentIndex < fullList.length) {
       var sliceStart = currentIndex;
       var sliceEnd = currentIndex + BATCH_SIZE;
       batches.push(fullList.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd));
       currentIndex += BATCH_SIZE;
    }
    console.log(batches);
}
```

I have example of code in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/parantes/us18dob6/2/), I hope solve your problem! :)